# How to create sorting in custom field for both ASC and DESC at the same time?

Tags: wordpress

I am using custom field query plugin for wp in my site. I wanted to create sorting option for custom field 'price' for front end user to sort price from option lowest to highest and highest to lowest. To use the custom field query plugin, I register the function in my headwaytheme.

```
add_action('init', 'register_From_Price');
function register_From_Price(){
register_custom_queryable_field("From_Price", array("dataType"=>"numeric","order"=>"DESC"));
}
```

Then, I place the following codes:

```
<span class="lowest">
<a href="<?php echo add_query_arg('order_by','From_Price','order'=>'ASC');?>">Lowest</a>
</span>

<span class="highest">
<a href="<?php echo add_query_arg(  'order_by', 'From_Price' ); ?>">Highest</a>
</span>
```

It working for the highest to Lowest, but it is not working for the lowest to highest.

I wonder anyone using this plugin can help to advice, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what plugin you are talking about

but i guess this may work

```
 add_query_arg('order_by','From_Price','order'=>'DESC');
```